# Notation for indicating closure.

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to record in my notes a general definition for what has been introduced to me as the "generating class argument." A form of such argument is commonly seen in elementary measure theory, where one might argue that since $A \subset B$, it must be that $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(B)$, where $\sigma()$ here indicates something like a [closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator) which sends generators to sigma algebras/fields. I have not studied Category Theory yet, but would like to extend the notion a bit, so that I could say something like $$ A \subset B \Rightarrow \operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A) \subset \operatorname{cl}_{Y}(B)$$
where $Y$ is some notion that is idempotent,extensive,monotone (but doesn't necessarily send $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X})$). E.g. topological closedness. Is this intelligible/ is there such a notion of closure under $Y$? Apologies if the question is flawed, I'm a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: This is a little vague; it's hard to know what you have in mind without more examples of what kind of operators you want to consider. Can you give some examples of the "generating class argument"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific notation, we just say that $C:P(X)\to P(X)$ is *a* closure operator if your conditions hold.

More generally you can define closure operators over arbitrary posets just the way you did:
$C:P\to P$ is a closure operator if $(1)\ x\le C(x),\ (2)\ x\le y\implies C(x)\le C(y)$ and $(3)\ C(C(x))=C(x)$.

Remarkably, this is a special case of *monads* where arbitrary categories replace posets.
A monad on a category $\mathcal A$ is a functor $C:\mathcal A\to\mathcal A$ (corresponding to $(2)$) together with natural transformations $\eta:{\rm id}_{\mathcal A}\to C$ (implying the existence of arrows $a\to C(a)$ hence corresponding to $(1)$) and $\mu:C^2\to C$ (corresponding to $(3)$ in the presence of $(1)$) that satisfy certain commutativity conditions which all are automatic in a posetal category since every pair of parallel arrows commute there.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the notation (or lack thereof I suppose)!